# Setting a DatePicker's height

Tags: java, javafx

How can I set a `DatePicker`'s height?

Normally, you would set `prefHeight` or `maxHeight` like you do with buttons or labels. But it doesn't seem to be working with `DatePicker`.

```
 DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
 pane.getChildren().add(datePicker);
 datePicker.setMaxHeight(16);
```

Note that, I'm only interested in the "input field"'s height. The popup calendar is fine.

Setting the `scaleY` property works, but of course is squishes everything...

Comment: Have you tried changing the size of the font used by the input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need the `setPrefHeight()` Method to set your preferred height to the `DatePicker`.

[image: Example]

Here is some example code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
        datePicker.setMinHeight(12.);
        datePicker.setPrefHeight(16.);
        datePicker.setMaxHeight(60.);
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.getChildren().add(new Label("DatePicker with 60px height"));
        hBox.getChildren().add(datePicker);

        HBox hBox1 = new HBox();
        DatePicker datePicker1 = new DatePicker();
        hBox1.getChildren().add(new Label("DatePicker with default height"));
        hBox1.getChildren().add(datePicker1);
        VBox vBox = new VBox(25);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(hBox, hBox1);
        root.getChildren().add(vBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setTitle("JavaFXs' DatePicker and the setPrefHeigth() method");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

With the `setMaxHeight()` Method you can override the Regions maximum computed size, you can read in the [DOCs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setMaxHeight-double-)

UPDATE:

use the `setMinHeight()` Method, to set the Minimum Height on your `DatePicker` (use a value which is lower then your preferred Height) and then you can also use 16 as your preferred height.

[image: Picture 2 with setMinHeight()]

Code snippet

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
datePicker.setMinHeight(12.);
datePicker.setPrefHeight(16.);
HBox hBox = new HBox();
hBox.getChildren().add(new Label("DatePicker with 16px height"));
hBox.getChildren().add(datePicker);
```

Patrick

Comment: I see what's up. It doesn't work with 16 because it is too low. I guess it cannot be bypassed?